# Luis Test Tool Datetime different than Locally Resolved Datetime

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding, timex

I have a Luis model created for a bot skill. I'm using the prebuilt `datetime` entity for dates.

When I give sample utterance such as *"Sell 5k [jargon] for this weekend at [jargon]"* on the Luis portal's test tool, I get the response I expect (shown below). The timex is `2020-W02-WE` and resolves to 1/11 - 1/13.

*Note that for the example below, I used "this weekend" as the query, but it resolves the same regardless of whether I enter an utterance that matches my skill intent. "this weekend" was used for simplicity in the example.*

Expected:

```
{
  "query": "this weekend",
  "prediction": {
    "normalizedQuery": "this weekend",
    "topIntent": "None",
    "intents": {
      "None": {
        "score": 0.8771556
      }
    },
    "entities": {
      "datetimeV2": [
        {
          "type": "daterange",
          "values": [
            {
              "timex": "2020-W02-WE",
              "start": "2020-01-11",  *** Saturday ***
              "end": "2020-01-13"     ***  Monday  ***
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "$instance": {
        "datetimeV2": [
          {
            "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange",
            "text": "this weekend",
            "startIndex": 0,
            "length": 12,
            "modelTypeId": 2,
            "modelType": "Prebuilt Entity Extractor",
            "recognitionSources": [
              "model"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I use the same utterance locally, I'm getting a date range representing the whole week 1/6/2020 - 1/13/2020 (Monday - Monday). The Timex is the same; however, when I resolve it, I'm getting a different value.

Luis Response to Emulator using utterance "this weekend":

```
{
  "recognizerResult": {
    "alteredText": null,
    "entities": {
      "$instance": {
        "datetime": [
          {
            "endIndex": 12,
            "startIndex": 0,
            "text": "this weekend",
            "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange"
          }
        ]
      },
      "datetime": [
        {
          "timex": [
            "2020-W02-WE"
          ],
          "type": "daterange"
        }
      ]
    },
    "intents": {
      "None": {
        "score": 0.8771556
      }
    },
    "text": "this weekend"
  }
}
```

```cs
// 2020-W01-WE - This should resolve to weekend; doesn't work locally, works on Luis. 
Resolution resolution = 
  TimexResolver.Resolve(((List<string>)options.Entities.datetime[0].Expressions).ToArray());

var start = resolution.Values?[0].Start; // 01/06/2020
var end = resolution.Values?[0].End;     // 01/13/2020
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong with how I'm resolving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, this looks like it certainly should work. I think it's a bug in the TimexResolver, so I've written a unit test and submitted a PR to the team - you can see it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/pull/2020) (ironically it's PR "2020").

If you need this fix super urgently, you can pull [my copy of TimexResolver](https://github.com/HiltonGiesenow/Recognizers-Text/blob/HandleWeekend_2020-W02-WE/.NET/Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression/TimexResolver.cs) into your own project, and rename it (e.g. TimexResolve2) while we wait for the PR to be reviewed and hopefully accepted.

[Update] The PR was already been accepted and merged into master (that was quick!). You can see it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/blob/master/.NET/Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression/TimexResolver.cs) - now we just need to wait for the next release of Recognizers-Text, or just download/clone the project locally for now, an watch for releases on GH